# Safari / Chrome - Flexbox grid

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, saas

I tried to implement a grid using flexbox and sass. It is working perfectly on Chrome but I have some issues with Safari and the red boxes are "overflowed" and does not break to a new line

Important point, when the Safari windows is smaller than the resolution screen it is working.

It might be better to create a new html file to test the problem and opening this file with safari and chrome.

## Safari (horizontal overflow, we have to scroll)

[image: Safari]

## Chrome

[image: Chrome]

```css
<style>
    .flex-parent {
      display: flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      margin-left: -14px;
      margin-top: -14px;
      margin-bottom: 14px;
    }
    .flex-parent .event_card {
      flex: 1 0 345px;
      -webkit-flex: 1 0 345px;
      margin-left: 14px;
      margin-top: 14px;
      padding: 14px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 140px;
      background: red;
    }
    @media (min-width: 690px) {
      .flex-parent .event_card {
        max-width: calc( 50% - 14px);
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1035px) {
      .flex-parent .event_card {
        max-width: calc( 33.33333333% - 14px);
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1035px) {
      .flex-parent .event_card {
        min-width: calc(33.33333333% - 14px);
      }
    }

</style>
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="flex-parent feedify-item-body">
                    
            <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="event_card">
                <div class="wrapper Aligner">
                    <div class="card__front"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Could you please help me by telling me what is wrong and what could be a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be related to

```
flex: 1 0 345px;
-webkit-flex: 1 0 345px;
```

I changed that to

```
flex: 1 0 calc( 33.33333333% - 14px);
-webkit-flex: calc( 33.33333333% - 14px);
```